# Quando usar finalizadores e coleta de lixo em Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, gerenciamento-de-memória, jvm, garbage-collector

Quando usar os métodos `System.gc()` e `finalize()`? Li que é muito útil em orientação a objetos para destruir objetos da memória que não estão sendo referenciados e para finalizar tarefas, mas vejo poucos programadores usando.
*Exemplo usado, retirado do livro Java Guia do programador 2ª edição.*

```java
package OrientacaoObjetos;

public class Objeto {
     private static int instancias = 0;
     private int id;

     public Objeto() {
         id = instancias++;
         System.out.println("Objeto.Objeto() [id=" + id + "]");
     }

     public static int getInstancias() { return instancias; }

     public int getId() { return id; }

     @Override
     public void finalize() {
         instancias--;
         System.out.println("Objeto.finalize() [id=" + id+ "]");
     }
}
```

```java
package OrientacaoObjetos;

public class TesteGC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Instancias = " + Objeto.getInstancias());
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Objeto o = new Objeto();
        }
        System.out.println("Instancias = " + Objeto.getInstancias());
        System.gc();
        System.out.println("Instancias = " + Objeto.getInstancias());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

O [método `finalize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize--) é uma das coisas mais odiadas no Java.

A recomendação em geral é não usá-lo nunca!

Em geral, tentar fazer a limpeza de recurso no `finalize()` não é boa prática porque:

- Frequentemente, o `finalize()` é sobrescrito para fazer limpezas desnecessárias, tal como setar referências a objetos para `null`. O coletor de lixo já é esperto o suficiente para fazer isso sozinho sem precisar de ajuda.
- Código que utiliza o `finalize()` é muuuito mais lento. A presença do método `finalize()` força a JVM a fazer trabalho extra e inibe um monte de otimizações, além de complicar bastante o gerenciamento de memória no Java.
- O método `finalize()` pode ressuscitar objetos mortos, inclusive objetos para os quais o método `finalize()` já foi chamado anteriormente.
- A execução do método `finalize()` não é garantida e nem previsível. É possível inclusive que a JVM não os invoque nunca. Ou os invoque muito tempo depois de o objeto em questão ter morrido.
- O método `finalize()` incentiva uma má prática de programação, a de que o objeto pode fazer a sua própria limpeza ao invés de o programador fazê-la. Quase sempre o coletor de lixo sabe fazer as limpezas adequadas sozinho. Nos casos mais complexos, é recomendável usar um bloco *try-finally* ou *try-with-resources*.
- O método `finalize()` é executado em uma *thread* gerenciada pelo coletor de lixo. Se implementado de forma inadequada, isso pode resultar em degradação de desempenho do coletor de lixo, ou até mesmo em um *deadlock* ou outros problemas com *threads* interferindo com o coletor de lixo, o que é algo seríssimo.
- As `ReferenceQueue`s do java são uma alternativa muito mais limpa do que usar o método `finalize()`. Veja mais sobre isso [aqui](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/index.html#jprofiler.helptopics.cpu.finalizers).

Enfim, é muuuito difícil achar uma situação aonde o `finalize()` se justifica. Só vi até hoje duas situações aonde ele se justifica:

- Quando o objeto em questão contém referências a buffers ou a objetos que estão fora da JVM, sendo implementados nativamente por meio de JNI. Neste caso, o `finalize()` é algo que serve para evitar *memory-leaks* e corrupção de memória.
- Para dar uma mensagem do tipo `System.out.println("Erro: O objeto XPTO não foi finalizado adequadamente");`, mas mesmo assim isso só seria para os objetos que realmente precisam de algo muito especial para serem fechados e ainda assim essa prática é questionável.

Quanto ao `System.gc()`, o coletor de lixo normalmente faz um ótimo trabalho para decidir quando é uma boa hora para ser executado, sem precisar da sua ajuda, e portanto você não deveria precisar do `System.gc()`. O `System.gc()` é apenas uma sugestão, e a JVM pode ignorá-lo por completo se assim preferir. Além disso, o uso de `System.gc()` pode causar sérios gargalos de desempenho ao fazer o coletor de lixo executar em horas inadequadas ou de forma redundante. E quase sempre que o `System.gc()` é utilizado, a pessoa que o colocou lá não entende direito o que está fazendo.

A partir do Java 9, o método `finalize()` foi tornado obsoleto (`@Deprecated`). Eis o que foi adicionado no [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize--):

> *The finalization mechanism is inherently problematic. Finalization can lead to performance issues, deadlocks, and hangs. Errors in finalizers can lead to resource leaks; there is no way to cancel finalization if it is no longer necessary; and no ordering is specified among calls to `finalize` methods of different objects. Furthermore, there are no guarantees regarding the timing of finalization. The `finalize` method might be called on a finalizable object only after an indefinite delay, if at all. Classes whose instances hold non-heap resources should provide a method to enable explicit release of those resources, and they should also implement [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) if appropriate. The [`Cleaner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html) and [`PhantomReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) provide more flexible and efficient ways to release resources when an object becomes unreachable.*

Traduzindo para o português:

> *O mecanismo de finalização é inerentemente problemático. A finalização pode levar a problemas de desempenho, deadlocks, e travamentos. Erros em finalizadores podem ocasionar vazamentos de recursos; não há forma de cancelar-se uma finalização se ela não for mais necessária; e nenhuma ordenação é especificada entre chamadas aos métodos `finalize` de diferentes objetos. Além disso, não há garantias quanto a hora em que a finalização ocorrerá. O método `finalize` pode ser chamado em um objeto finalizável apenas depois de uma espera por tempo indefinido, se for de fato chamado. Classes nas quais as instâncias guardam referências a recursos fora do heap devem prover um método para explicitamente liberar tais recursos, e elas devem também implementar  [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) se apropriado. O [`Cleaner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html) e o [`PhantomReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) proveem meios mais flexíveis e eficientes de se liberar recursos quando um objeto se torna inalcançável.*

Veja em especial estes links:

- http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/31/why-not-to-use-finalize-method-in-java/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2414621/540552
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/158370/540552
- http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/index.html#jprofiler.helptopics.cpu.finalizers

Answer (score 10):

Não usam porque não é para usar mesmo. Deve existir um forte motivo para usá-los diretamente em código de aplicação em produção e raramente existe este forte motivo.

Em geral o `System.gc()` é usado em códigos de teste ou que precisem de otimização extrema (mesmo estas eu tenho minhas dúvidas), isto não é nada comum.

Chamá-lo causa problemas. Não vou entrar em detalhes mas memória separada em gerações deve evitar coletas o máximo possível e este método força a sua execução, quase sempre sem trazer qualquer tipo de ganho, pelo contrário.

Se usar e não for uma execução de perfilamento, está fazendo algo errado. E se não dominar seu uso, até nesta situação, estará fazendo algo errado. Há muito mito sobre isto.

O `finalize` deve ser invocado pelo coletor de lixo e não para ser chamado individualmente. Pelo menos não em condições normais. Apenas casos muito específicos, provavelmente apenas em momento de teste de alguma coisa ele pode ser chamado manualmente. Depender dele sendo invocado manualmente para sua aplicação funcionar é um enorme erro.

Note que este método pode nunca ser chamado, mesmo pelo coletor de lixo.

Para ambos existe bastante literatura confiável dizendo para não usá-los. A [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()), o livro [Effective Java](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA27#v=onepage&q&f=false) e a [pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2414105/221800) são exemplos.

Então você não vê os programadores usando ou porque eles sabem que não devem usar ou porque não conhecem nada sobre o assunto e por sorte ficam longe disto, o que é bem adequado.

Após a edição e colocação do código do livro nota-se que o exemplo é apenas um teste ou demonstração. Não é um código de produção real, então é coerente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O livro é Java Guia do programador 2edição.

Comment: Tem citar na sua pergunta o trecho que diz isso. Conforme for vou exorcizar o livro :D

Comment: @bigown, já passou por problemas de gerenciamento de memória?

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino depende de qual, já passei por vários, mas cada um tem sua peculiaridade.

Comment: @bigown, exemplo: CPU 100% no servidor ou outOfMemory

Comment: @WellingtonAvelino 100% de CPU não é problema de gerenciamento de memória. Já tive *outOfMemory* mas não em Java. Eu nunca programei em Java de verdade :D

Comment: hahaha, entendi! @bigown

Answer (score 6):

Gostaria de adicionar sobre os *[finalizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finalizer)* e sua interação com o GC (coletor de lixo):

1. Eles são executados de **forma assíncrona** à thread do Garbage Collector, essa outra é uma [Daemon Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java) de finalizadores pendentes, de baixa prioridade. É um comum equívoco acreditar que uma *major* ou *minor* *collection* faz com que a thread do GC fique aguardando a execução de cada finalizador das instâncias coletadas.
2. Não existe nenhum esoterismo ao fato de não haver garantia quanto a execução dos finalizadores. Isso ocorre porque [Daemon Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213340/what-is-daemon-thread-in-java), como a `Finalizer System Thread` da JVM não impedem (seguram) a finalização do processo JVM, ou seja, quando a *main thread* (do `Main Thread Group`) termina, ela interrompe todas as *system threads* e consequentemente a execução os *finalizares* que estão em fila.
3. Como expliquei anteriormente, **o GC não executa finalizadores**, apenas os adiciona em fila de execução (finalizadores pendentes) de baixa prioridade. Por esse fato **ele não desaloca a memória nesse momento**. Isso pode ser crítico ao processo de coleção de lixo e consequentemente à aplicação caso a execução dos finalizadores tome *tempo*, vez que esse seria um clássico caso de [memory leak](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html).
4. Você também pode **sugerir** a JVM que ela **priorize** a execução dos métodos finalizadores pendentes, usando `Runtime.getRuntime().runFinalization()` ou `System.runFinalization()`.
5. Existe um método `System.runFinalizersOnExit(true)` que pode ser usada para forçar o processo da JVM a aguardar a execução de todos os *finalizers* antes da sua finalização. Esse método está descontinuado e é inseguro. Citando a [documentação da classe](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/System.java#System.runFinalization%28%29):

   > This method is inherently unsafe. It may result in finalizers being
   >   called on live objects while other threads are concurrently
   >   manipulating those objects, resulting in erratic behavior or deadlock.

   Que traduzindo para o português é:

   > Este método é inerentemente inseguro. Ele pode resultar em finalizadores sendo
   >   chamados em objetos vivos enquanto outras threads estiverem concorrentemente
   >   manipulando esses objetos, resultando em comportamento errático ou deadlock.