# Método "finalize" em Java

Tags: java, método, garbage-collector

Como funciona o método "finalize" em Java? Ele é chamado de forma implícita? Logo abaixo há um código com esse método que não consigo entender. A classe `EmployeeTest` chama esse método, mas não sei como.

```
package employee;

public class Employee{

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public static int count = 0;

    public Employee (String first, String last) {

       firstName = first;
       lastName = last;
       count++;
       System.out.printf("Employee constructor: %s %s; count = %d\n",
               firstName,lastName,count); 
    }

    protected void finalize(){
        count--;
        System.out.printf("Employee finalizer: %s %s ; count = %d\n",
                firstName,lastName,count);
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }
    public static int getCount(){
        return count;
    }

}
```

```
package employee;

public class EmployeeTest{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        System.out.printf("Employees before instantiation: %d\n",
                Employee.getCount());

        Employee e1 = new Employee("Susan","Baker");
        Employee e2 = new Employee ("Bob","Blue");

        System.out.println("\nEmployees after instantiation: ");
        System.out.printf("via e1.getCount(): %d\n",e1.getCount());
        System.out.printf("via e2.getCount(): %d\n",e2.getCount());
        System.out.printf("via Employee.getCount(): %d\n",
                Employee.getCount());

        System.out.printf("\nEmployee 1: %s %s\nEmployee 2: %s %s",
                e1.getFirstName(),e1.getLastName(),
                e2.getFirstName(),e2.getLastName());

        // objetos marcados para a coleta de lixo, pois não são mais referenciados.
        e1 = null;
        e2 = null;

        System.gc();

        System.out.printf("\nEmployees afters System.gc():",
                Employee.getCount());        

    }

}
```

Saída do programa:

> Employees before instantiation: 0 Employee constructor: Susan Baker;
>   count = 1 Employee constructor: Bob Blue; count = 2
>
> Employees after instantiation:  via e1.getCount(): 2 via
>   e2.getCount(): 2 via Employee.getCount(): 2
>
> Employee 1: Susan Baker Employee 2: Bob Blue Employees afters
>   System.gc():Employee finalizer: Bob Blue ; count = 1 Employee
>   finalizer: Susan Baker ; count = 0 CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo
>   total: 0 segundos)

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

O método é chamado pelo coletor de lixo do Java quando ele entra em ação.

Note que ele está presente em todos os objetos do Java, já que é implementado pelo tipo [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize--) do qual todos tipos por referência são herdados.

O exemplo sobrescreveu o método original. Potencialmente introduziu um problema que só seria notado em um código mais complexo. Normalmente não se recomenda fazer isso a não ser que tenha estrita necessidade e o programador entende todas as implicações do que ele está fazendo.

Entenda que esse exemplo tinha o claro objetivo de mostrar isso funcionando. O adequado aí seria não ter esse método que não faz nada útil, e mais ainda, [o coletor de lixo não deveria ser chamado explicitamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110854/101). Esse exemplo funcionou quase por acaso. [Sequer há garantias que ele executará](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105092/101). Além disto a maioria dos códigos reais que anulam um objeto explicitamente está fazendo algo errado. Não faça algo desse exemplo em código real. Espero que a fonte tenha notado isso e não fique disseminando informação errada por aí.

Mais informações sobre o [funcionamento do *garbage coletor* e os finalizadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76601/101).

[Artigo na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finalizer).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).